# SQL to count rows in a group where a column is equal to a particular value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have a table with columns CMDNAME, TIME, and FAILED.  There are a number of rows with the same CMDNAME value.  The TIME column is just a timestamp for the transaction.  The FAILED column is either "Y" or "N".

I want my result to be, for each distinct value of CMDNAME, the ratio of rows with FAILED='Y' to the total number of rows (for the same CMDNAME value).

I can get sort of close with the following:

```
select CMDNAME, FAILED, count(*) groupCount from TABLE group by CMDNAME, FAILED
```

That gives me two rows for each unique CMDNAME value, one with the "N" count and one with the "Y" count.  I could use this, with some intermediate computation, if I can't figure out the more direct way to compute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using the `count` window function.

```
select distinct CMDNAME, 
1.0*count(case when failed = 'Y' then 1 end) over(partition by CMDNAME)
/count(*) over(partition by CMDNAME) as groupCount 
from TABLE
```

or using conditional aggregation.

```
select CMDNAME, 
1.0*count(case when failed = 'Y' then 1 end)/count(*) as groupCount 
from TABLE 
group by CMDNAME
```

Comment: Both answers are fine, you got in 1 minute earlier. :) The key understanding for me was the "count(case ...)" notation.

Comment: The first version will be quite inefficient compared to the second (why create one row of output for every row of input, only to use select **distinct** on the result? That's what aggregation is for). In both cases, the 1.0* ...  is unnecessary; unfortunately, Oracle doesn't "know" integer arithmetic, so there's no need to "tell it" you are looking for floating point computations. Those are the only ones Oracle does.

Answer (score 1):

`count`, like many aggregate functions, skips `null`s. You could use this property and count a `case` expression that reports only the `failed='Y'` rows:

```
SELECT   cmdname,
         COUNT(*) AS all_rows
         COUNT(CASE failed WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS only_failures,
         COUNT(CASE failed WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS failure_ratio
FROM     mytbale
GROUP BY cmdname
```